# ввод переменных в php

Tags: php

скажите пожалуйста.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
$a=2;
$x=4+$a;
echo "ответ будет $x ";
?>
```

у меня вот такой  элементарный код, но я хочу, чтобы `$a` ввел пользователь с клавиатуры.

как вызвать оператора и строку в которую ввести `$a`?

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Если вы собираетесь запускать скрипт с консоли, [readline()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readline.php) - то что вам надо:

```
<?php
$a=readline("a=");      
echo "your input is $a\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать например html-форму:

Страница с формой(например `form.php`):

```
<form action="script.php">
   <input name="param_name" />
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

И обработчик:

Например(`script.php` как указано в теге `<form>` атрибутом `action`):

```
<?php
$var = $_GET['param_name']; //индекс зависит от имени поля

echo 'recived: ' . $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша задача решается с помощью форм. Для примера приведу простую форму:

**Index.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="get">
Имя: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
Фамилия: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<html>
<body>

Привет <?php echo $_GET["firstName"]; ?> <?php echo $_GET["lastName"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Удачного кодинга...